# Dockerfile для элементарной HelloWorld.java

Tags: docker

Если использовать готовый контейнер с Java:
Вот Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:7
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /home/alexkup/Dropbox/HW/02/src
RUN javac Hellodocker.java
CMD ["java", "Hellodocker"]
```

, на что мне выдает:

```
lexkup@alexkup-SVE1511N1RW:~/Dropbox/HW/02$ sudo docker build -t alexkup/hellodocker /home/alexkup/Dropbox/HW/02
Sending build context to Docker daemon   105 kB
Step 1 : FROM java:7
 ---> e93dd201a77e
Step 2 : COPY . /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ecd81ca38846
Step 3 : WORKDIR /home/alexkup/Dropbox/HW/02/src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 248957b17db1
Step 4 : RUN javac Hellodocker.java
 ---> Running in f9faa6229355
javac: file not found: Hellodocker.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
The command '/bin/sh -c javac Hellodocker.java' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Не может найти Hellodocker.java?
Вот путь к нему `/home/alexkup/Dropbox/HW/02/src`

Путь к Dockerfile `/home/alexkup/Dropbox/HW/02`

Подскажите, на какой строчке я не правильно пишу. Или в чем может быть проблема?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Я не вижу в вашем контейнере, где вы java вообще устанавливаете.

Comment: `FROM ubuntu:14.04` -- вы понимаете, что начинаете с **абсолютно чистой системы**?

Comment: @Suvitruf , Вы имеете ввиду команду или путь?

Comment: @Alex.Kuptsov у вас в докер контейнере голая убунта. Там java нет вообще. Ваша программа не может быть запущено в принципе.

Comment: @D-side , скорее всего не понимаю. Задача создать контейнер для элементарной .java. Нужен пример Dockerfile.

Comment: @Alex.Kuptsov плюс что вы там собираетесь запускать? Я не вижу, где вы скопировали ваш проект внутрь контейнера.

Comment: @Suvitruf , скопировать командой в Dockerfile или в директорию?

Comment: @Alex.Kuptsov да, командой `COPY` или `ADD` в Dockefile

Comment: @Suvitruf ,  пробую использовать готовый образ, я вопрос изменил

Comment: @Suvitruf , добавил финальный Dockerfile

Comment: @Alex.Kuptsov да не надо `COPY . /src` вместо этого вы должны указать путь для приложения на локальной машине

Comment: @Suvitruf , спасибо, разобрался. Поместил и запустил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо используйте уже [готовый контейнер с Java](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/), а не ubuntu:14.04:

```
FROM java:7
# ./myapp - директория на локальной машине с приложением
COPY ./myapp  /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac Hellodocker.java
CMD ["java", "Hellodocker"]
```

Либо при билде контейнера устанавливайте Java сами:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Alex Kuptsov <alex.kuptsov@gmail.com>

# Install all prerequisites
RUN     apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN     apt-get -y update
RUN \
 echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
 add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
 apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
 rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
 rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer 

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

COPY ./myapp  /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

RUN javac Hellodocker.java

CMD ["java", "Hellodocker"]
```

Comment: Step 5 : RUN apt-get -y openjdk-7-jre
 ---> Running in 75356f4e641e
E: Command line option 'y' [from -y] is not known.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y openjdk-7-jre' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: 5 этап не проходит

Comment: ОК, а если готовый контейнер с Java, какого вида он должен быть, чтоб запускать мой hellodocker.java?

Comment: @Alex.Kuptsov попробуйте не с Openjdk, а с Oracle Java. Я обновил ответ.

Comment: ок, спасибо, попробую

Comment: дальше 7го этапа не идет

Comment: @Alex.Kuptsov обновил ответ